# How to make a correct authorization

Tags: swift

i am making an app Redmine, i have a website with a user with pass and there are issues. But i can't understand what i should do to make authorization.

Here I have Router, Request, AuthViewController. I also wanted to ask how i have to make AuthRequest? What has to be there?

AuthViewController
import UIKit

```
class AuthViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInBotton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func signInDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
        login()
    }
    fileprivate func login(){
        AuthRequest.login(email: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!){(user, error) in DispatchQueue.main.async {
            [unowned self] in self.openIssues()
            }
    }
}

}

//extension AuthViewController: Router{
//    func prepare() {
//    Here error with 'seque'    if(seque.identifier = Seque.issues.rawValue){
//            print("It's OK")
//            guard let controller = seque.destination as? IssuesViewController else { print("Wrong destination"); return}
//            //controller.presenter = IssuesPresenter();
//        }
//    }
//
//    func openIssues() {
//        print("kek")
//    }
//
//
//    enum Seque: String {
//        case issues = "IssuesSeque"
//    }
//
//}
```

There is also an error in if-block in extension.

Comment: Just checking, you have imported the relevant frameworks as I can't see from the snippet? Also, is `AuthRequest` returning an error, i.e. check if `error` is not nil? You also need to use `==` on the if-block rather than `=`.

Comment: @LeonStorey i have corrected if-block. I don't have AuthRequest, i need help to make it, what should it have? IDE also wants to change seque in extension to Seque.

Comment: Ah apologises, I thought you were using an existing auth framework. Details of the Redmine authentication for REST API can [be found here](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api). I'm assuming you're using email/password basic authentication? Although I'd strongly recommend using API Key rather than plain password. Also have you checked `Enable REST API` in `Administration -> Settings -> API`?

Comment: @LeonStorey yes, i use apiKey in class Request. Also i can't understand the architecture that i have to use: where is presenter, interactor etc.

Comment: What you're after is much broader than the original question, and typically not what StackOverflow is intended for. Although, hopefully I can help guide you somewhat. I assume you're using `URLRequest` class to build the HTTP request to Redmine's REST API when you refer to class Request? As per the documentation I linked earlier, you should be able to either set a HTTP header `X-Redmine-API-Key` with value being your API Key or by adding a query string key `key=APIKEY` to each request. Such that on Redmine, you don't need an auth token like OAuth 2.0, instead it's a per request basis.